# How do I know if an update requires restart in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, software-update, restart

How do I know if an update requires restart in macOS Sierra? I just updated iTunes and read the description of the update, but couldn't find any mention of a restart required. After a moment the computer restarted without a warning. Luckily, I wasn't in the middle of anything important, but I'd like to avoid such forced restarts in the future.

Edit: There was also a macOS Sierra update today. In the figure below, there's no mention of a restart required. I also followed the two links, but found no mention there either. I'm pretty sure that the info shown here was the same prior to the update.
[image: Screenshot of one of the updates installed recently in App Store]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the Updates list in the Mac App Store, it will indicate in the info if a restart is required. Below is an example of this:

[image: Restart Required]

You will see the words *Restart Required* followed by an icon of a white triangle within a grey circle (looks like a reverse *play* button).

Prior to installing the update, just check the info against each update to see whether any of them require a restart.

Security updates and OS updates usually require a restart. Most other apps don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've edited my question and provided a counterexample. I was expecting a restart, of course, ensuing a system update.

Comment: Yes, but the screenshot you've added to your question was taken of the update **after** it was installed. This will no longer indicate that a restart was required. The indication of a restart being required is only present _before_ you install it. In addition, I also know that sometimes people click on Update All (in the case of multiple updates) and get caught out because one of them required a restart. So you really do need to check all of them if choosing to install multiple updates simultaneously. I've updated my answer to show you an example.

Comment: Prior to the update I really tried to find a notification of a restart, but I guess I somehow managed to miss that. Well, thank you anyway! Now I know where to look in the future.

Comment: The UI has changed somewhat since this screenshot was taken. Would be helpful to have an updated answer.

Comment: @a06e Hmm, that's a valid point, although this question was specific to macOS Sierra, and it's interface hasn't changed.

Comment: So should I ask a new question @Monomeeth ?

Comment: @a06e What's your situation? It may be a new question, or we may be able to edit this Q & A to also reflect newer versions of macOS.